# How to change the color and formatting of column header row in datagrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagridview, wpfdatagrid

I tried looking for the solutions, but most are outdated and are not available currently. For example

```
_dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

There is no columnheadesdefaultcellstyle anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For a WPF DataGrid there is a ColumnHeaderStyle that can be set where you can alter the look and feel of the header row.

```
   <Style x:Key="FADataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
      <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Horizontal"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColorBrush}"/>
      <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource FADataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
      <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow"/>
   </Style>

   <Style x:Key="FADataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationLightFont}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
   </Style>
```

Now on the XAML data grid definition you set the style. (Note the FADataGridStyle)

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
               CanUserAddRows="False"
               CanUserSortColumns="True"
               CanUserReorderColumns="True"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Recordings}"
               RowHeaderWidth="0"
               SelectionMode="Single"
               ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
               Background="{StaticResource SurfaceColorBrush}"
               Style="{StaticResource FADataGridStyle}">
```

I believe this results on what you are asking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ColTips.FilteredPayments}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=PaymentDate}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here you can do it inline by just setting a style on the desired column.